# Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 autocomplete selectors based on my HTML markup?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

Imagine I have this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

In my CSS file, when I type in:

```
#
```

Is there a way to make Visual Studio show me intellisense of all id's in my HTML markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Visual Studio itself doesn't provide an inbuilt functionally to autocomplete classes or ids.

Luckily there is a plugin which is providing this feature: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
I'm using it and it provides me with a list of classes or ids like intellisense.

Comment: Didn't know it did this. You might win this bounty!

Comment: Resharper has recently updated to be able to parse html and javascript: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/

Comment: Resharper v6 has that. But then, it cause Out of memory exception so many times on my 32bit, quad core, 4GB RAM desktop. When it doesn't crash, VS 2010 simply crawls slower than a tired snail. I have suspended Resharper now till I get a better box. So take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Also, R# will show available classes in UserControls and places where VS2010 doesn't show a thing. Which is a big + as well with V6.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do that.

However the Visual Studio intellisense can show you all property names and the relative attributes you can use, so if you want to add a property that you don't remember, just press Ctrl + spacebar and you will see all CSS 2.1 properties.

You can also view all property attributes by typing the ":" after a property name, e.g. this is what you will see by typing "background:"

```
background: [background-color] [background-image] [background-repeat] [background-attachment] [background-position] | inherit
```